# Check if href is undefined, if true alert smth (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, class, href

I want to check if the "href" of an `<a>` tag is empty, if that's true it should alert something like "The site isn't available atm", if the link is correct it should do nothing.

HTML

```
<a onclick="testif();" class="link" href="www.google.com">This Link is defined</a>
<a onclick="testif();" class="link" href="">This Link is undefined</a>
```

JavaScript

```
function testif(){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("link").getAttribute("href") == ""){
    Alert("Site isn't available")

    }else {

    // if the link is correct, alert nothing
   }
};
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

A way could you potentially do it is pass the event in and check the [event's target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/n6z52swt/1/)

```js
function testif (e) {
  // prevent from actually going to another url, feel free to remove the line
  e.preventDefault();
  // in case of IE 6-8 support
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (!target.getAttribute('href')) alert("Site isn't available");
}
```

```html
<a onclick="testif(event)" class="link" href="www.google.com">This Link is defined</a>
<a onclick="testif(event)" class="link" href="">This Link is undefined</a>
```

Comment: Just be aware of IE when using e.target

Comment: @B.Assem very true, but that is for older IE versions (6-8). Hopefully OP doesn't have to support something that old. However, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to support that old versions ^^

Comment: <a onclick="testif(this)" ...> will pass a reference to the link element itself.

Comment: @PatrickDenny used event to preventDefault so the demo wouldn't go to the url being used, but that too would work.

Answer (score 2):

You can get and test the clicked link via `event.target`:

```js
function testif(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  target = e.target || e.srcElement; // Support for IE6-8
  if (target.getAttribute("href") == "") {
    console.log("Site isn't available")
};
```

```html
<a onclick="testif(event);" class="link" href="http://www.google.com">This Link is defined</a>
<a onclick="testif(event);" class="link" href="">This Link is undefined</a>
```

or shorter syntax:

```
function testif(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  target = e.target || e.srcElement; // Support for IE6-8
  (target.getAttribute("href")) || console.log("Site isn't available")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, `getElementsByClassName` yields *multiple* elements; the combination of their `href` attributes could never be equal to an empty string.

Comment: Is there an other way to fix this then? :D

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName` return a collection of element, you will need to loop through each element to check it's href

```
function testif(){
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].getAttribute("href") == ""){
            alert('Site isn't available');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```